# Error When Altering Table - invalid ALTER TABLE option

Tags: oracle

1. 

```sql
CREATE TABLE STUDENT 
(STUDENT_ID NUMBER (10),
Matriculation_Date DATE, 
Enrollment_Status VARCHAR (11),
Enrollment_Effective_Date DATE, 
First_Name VARCHAR (20), 
Last_Name VARCHAR (20),
Address_Line_1 VARCHAR (20), 
Address_Line_2 VARCHAR (20), 
Address_Line_3 VARCHAR (20),
Telephone# Number(10),
Spouse_First_Name VARCHAR (20), 
Spouse_Last_Name VARCHAR (20),
ACADEMIC_ADVISOR_ID VARCHAR(25));
```

2. 

```sql
 CREATE TABLE ENROLLMENT_STATUS
(STUDENT_ID NUMBER(10),
ENROLLED VARCHAR(1),
FULL_TIME VARCHAR(1),
PART_TIME VARCHAR(1),
ON_LEAVE VARCHAR(1),
WITHDRAWN VARCHAR(1));
```

3. 

```sql
 CREATE TABLE THESIS_ADVISOR
(THESIS_ADVISOR_ID VARCHAR(20),
First_Name VARCHAR (20), 
Last_Name VARCHAR (20),
Office_Telephone_Number Number (10),
Office_Site CHAR (30));
```

4. 

```sql
CREATE TABLE ACADEMIC_ADVISOR
(ACADEMIC_ADVISOR_ID VARCHAR(20),
First_Name VARCHAR (20), 
Last_Name VARCHAR (20),
Office_Telephone_Number Number (10),
THESIS_COMMITEE_MEMBER VARCHAR(1),
THESIS_TITLE VARCHAR (20));
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE ACADEMIC_ADVISOR
(ADD PRIMARY KEY ASSIGNED_ADVISOR (ADVISOR_ID),
ADD FOREIGN KEY ASSIGNED_STUDENT(STUDENT_ID),
REFERENCES STUDENT (STUDENT_ID),
ADD FOREIGN KEY TH_ADVISOR (THESIS_ADVISOR_ID),
REFERENCES (THESIS_ADVISOR));
```

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -

```sql
ALTER TABLE ACADEMIC_ADVISOR
(ADD PRIMARY KEY ASSIGNED_ADVISOR (ADVISOR_ID),
ADD FOREIGN KEY ASSIGNED_STUDENT(STUDENT_ID),
REFERENCES STUDENT (STUDENT_ID),
ADD FOREIGN KEY TH_ADVISOR (THESIS_ADVISOR_ID),
REFERENCES (THESIS_ADVISOR))
```

> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
> 01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Comment: That isn't Oracle syntax for `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: Which is the correct Syntax to use?

Comment: Individual statements for each table e.g `alter table x add constraint constraint_name primary key (column_name)` for foreign key `alter table abc add constraint constraint_name foreign key(column_name) references parent_table(column_name)`.

Comment: The `ACADEMIC_ADVISOR` table structure does not contain the column `ADVISOR_ID` which is used in ALTER TABLE. Maybe you mean `ACADEMIC_ADVISOR_ID` column? The same with `STUDENT_ID` and `THESIS_ADVISOR_ID`. And the referal table is not specified in the last FK definition.

Comment: "Which is the correct Syntax to use? "  The _SQL Language Reference_ is at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/index.html  Please bookmark it.